# How to know when a user unfollows on Twitter

Tags: twitter

Twitter sends an email notification mentioning so-and-so-person [with their tweets, followers, etc info] is following me, the moment someone follows me.

But Twitter does not send any email after someone unfollows me.
Is it possible to know when someone unfollows me on Twitter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to track down the recent unfollowers on Twitter](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17303/how-to-track-down-the-recent-unfollowers-on-twitter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use **http://goodbyebuddy.com/**. Works well, with a nice responsive UI

Answer (score 3):

There are a few services and bots out there that perform this function, but the easiest to use appear to be [Qwitter](http://useqwitter.com) and [TwUnfollow](http://twunfollow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Another site, basically doing the same thing: [Who Unfollowed Me](http://who.unfollowed.me/)

The downside to all of these sites:
they only track your unfollowers from the moment you sign up with the site, so there is no way (as far as I know, and I've been looking ;) to find out who unfollowed you in the past.