# How to track down the recent unfollowers on Twitter

Tags: twitter, followers

Sometimes when I log in to Twitter, I realize that some users have stopped following me (there seems to be a decrease in the number of the followers). Is there a way to track down who those users are?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at http://who.unfollowed.me/

It will track the users that stop following you. As with pretty much all Twitter services it can't tell you who unfollowed you in the past. It only starts tracking from the time you sign up.

**free service**

> Do you ever wonder the age old question, who unfollowed me on twitter? Wonder no more! We allow you to easily check your unfollowers on your schedule, every 15 minutes, without waiting for an email or a direct message.

**Pro Service**

> Want more? We've got something special just for you.
>
> - automatically check unfollowers
> - unfollow those not following back
> - 45 day unfollower history
>     and more...

Answer (score 3):

Try [fllwrs](http://fllwrs.com/).

> Would you like to see a record of who follows and unfollows you every day?
>
> Would you like to get notified when someone unfollows you?

Answer (score 3):

[Formulist](http://formulists.com/) creates auto-updating twitter lists based on various factors such as

- Latest followers
- Latest unfollowers
- Latest people I've had conversations with

and so on

Answer (score 0):

[Unfollowers.me](http://unfollowers.me) is the nice app to manage followers and following. It gives a nice overview of your friends, followers, and more.
Optionally you can go for pay version, If you need more power.

Comment: Are you affiliated with that site? If so, you should disclose it.

Answer (score 0):

[JustUnfollow.com](http://www.justUnfollow.com) is a complete friend management dashboard for twitter. You can view who unfollowed you on twitter, your new followers, inactive users.

Many users want to start twitter all over again. JustUnfollow has a feature where you can unfollow everyone you follow.

JustUnfollow is on a mission to help everyone clean their twitter.

Free

- Tracking unfollowers
- Tracking new followers
- Fast unfollow and follow (50 per day)
- Whitelist & Blacklist (50 per day)

Pro ( start $9.99/year )

- Add multiple accounts
- Unlimited follows/unfollows (twitter rules apply)
- 10,000 whitelist & blacklist
- Auto tracking unfollowers/followers every hour (coming very soon)

**P.S.** I'm the founder of JustUnfollow

Comment: Does it show who unfollowed me prior the start of using this service?